# Getting the platform signing key

Tags: android, key, platform, android-source, sign

I need to know how can I get the platform signing key.
I googled a lot, but unable to find the step by step process for that.

Please guide me the way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The link below should help:

http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1267/

also, to generate the debug key to sign the apk you build outside platform build with "ant debug", you need to change one of the command in step 3 to :

$ keytool -changealias -alias 1 -destalias androidebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore